# NAN and Infinity in javascript mathematical operations

Tags: javascript, math

`0 / 0` outputs `NaN`
while `1 / 0` outputs `Infinity`

How javascript evaluates the first mathematical operation?

Comment: See this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN

Comment: not possible but exact duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript, `0 / 0` and `1 / 0` denote the division of IEEE754 floating point type arguments.

This floating point specification is very specific about what must happen when a division where the denominator is zero is evaluated. It returns

1. +Infinity if the numerator is positive
2. -Infinity if the numerator is negative
3. NaN if the numerator is also zero

Hence `0 / 0` is NaN, and `1 / 0` is +Infinity.

Note that in other languages (e.g. C, C++, and Java) your division would take place in *integer arithmetic*, and integer division by zero is not defined.

Answer (score 2):

As per [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-applying-the-div-operator)

**0 / 0 outputs NaN** because

> Division of a zero by a zero results in NaN; division of zero by any
>   other finite value results in zero, with the sign determined by the
>   rule already stated above.

and  **1 / 0 outputs Infinity** because

> Division of a nonzero finite value by a zero results in a signed
>   infinity. The sign is determined by the rule already stated above.

Point 7 and 8 in the section **12.6.3.2 Applying the / Operator** (unordered list)

Answer (score 0):

0/0 is the expression which math can not execute. that is why it is Not_A_Number.